# How to make column names the first row?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a query using dynamic pivot, so the column names change based on the data. My code generates a .csv file based on the result of the query. I don't know how I can make the header, as I cannot hard-code column names. Is it possible somehow to make the header of the query result the first row of the recordset?

Thanks.

ADDED: Just realized that I don't even know how to fetch the data in my C# code if I don't know what columns I have... So that I cannot do something like this:

```
   result.AddRange(from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                            select new DailyTransactionSheet
                                {
                                    Serve = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Serve"]),
                                    Remits = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Remits"]),
                                    List = Convert.ToInt32(dr["List"]),
                                    Billing = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Billing"]),
                                    DollarSent = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DollarSent"]),
                                    FileAck = Convert.ToInt32(dr["FileAck"]),
                                });
        }
```

Comment: Usually after execution of any query you can fetch information about column names, what language do you use?

Comment: This seems like the wrong approach, as the data types of all of the columns would have to be text-supporting for that to work. Could you give a concrete example of why you need dynamic columns?

Comment: I need to generate a report in .csv form of some statistics, e.g. count of items from various producers, so that each type of product would be a column, and the data is grouped by producer.

Comment: @DavidShochet if you're using SQLDataReader to fetch results, you can get column information from GetSchemaTable.Columns

Comment: Would it let me also solve the problem I added in my original question? I use SqlDataAdapter. Also, maybe you would like to make your answer an Answer, so that I could mark if accordingly if it works for me?

Comment: @DavidShochet `SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet)` `DataSet.Tables[0].Columns` - these methods and properties you should read about

Comment: Have you considered using SQL Server Integration Services?  Converting results to a .csv is a common requirement that is built into SSIS to make it easy...

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson: I like SSIS too, but in this situation, SSIS is *NOT* going to be easy:  he's going to run into similar questions -- how to deal with variable columns -- because, as he said in his first sentence, his query uses a dynamic pivot. To David Shochet: how about creating a predictable table, with extra columns that will not always be used?  Then you populate THAT table... and voila! (1) You have predictable column names, and (2) SSIS would *THEN* be an easy way to extract to CSV.

Comment: @Ilya Bursov I use your solution, and it worked. Thanks. Would you like make it an Answer, so that I could mark it accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per comments:

basically you need to execute query and fetch information about columns form it, depending on how your're executing it, there can be several options:

`SQLDataReader` to fetch results, you can get column information from `GetSchemaTable.Columns` [GetSchemaTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable.aspx)

or

`SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet)` `DataSet.Tables[0].Columns` - these methods and properties you should read about [DataSet.Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables.aspx)

here is example from msdn:

```
private void PrintRows(DataSet dataSet)
{
    // For each table in the DataSet, print the row values. 
    foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```